# database complex 3 way join query

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, join

[image: Tables]

Hi i have the following 3 tables, example data inside them

patients : 1,DUMMY PT, 78936, 1987-07-18

Custom_fields : **1** , 1 , 'blood pressure' , input , 'medical records'

patient_info  : 1, **1** , 80/90 blah blah , 1

---

what i want is when i very patient page, is to get ALL rows of 'patient_info' where pt_id=patients.patient_id and then get custom_fields.title=cf_id where doctor_id=$id 
and show all.

from above given example of data it should looks like this:

Patient: DuMMY pt profile page :-

blood pressure : 80/90 blah blah

any hints how i should join this tables together ?

Note: i tried :

```
SELECT patient_info.info,custom_fields.title FROM patient_info where patient_info.pt_id='8' and custom_fields.id=patient_info.cf_id and custom_fields.doctor_id = '10'
join patients on patient_info.pt_id=patients.patients_id
join custom_fields on patient_info.cf_id=custom_fields.id
```

where 10 and 8 are already givens ($vars in php) but im getting error near 'join patients on'

Comment: @ saharsh .->added on edits

Comment: Why are you joining other tables after where conditions. Syntax is Select then From then Joins then where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.info,cf.title 
FROM patient_info p
INNER JOIN patients ps ON p.pt_id=ps.patients_id
INNER JOIN custom_fields cf ON p.cf_id=cf.id
WHERE p.pt_id='8' AND cf.doctor_id = '10'
```

Comment: worked :d.. thanks didnt notice the where was before join :/ tyty

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code

```
select * from patients P,Custom_fields CF,patient_info PI where PI.pt_id=p.patient_id
and PI.cf_id=CF.id and CF.doctor_id='$id';
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel like it should be a [Left Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)